# How to sort documents containing products belonging to more than one location?

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrj

Suppose my index contains products with each product present at  multiple stores. How to sort products based on the minimum distance between user and all the stores belonging to that product. I have users longitude and latitude with me as well as longitude and latitude of stores.

I'm using solr 4. I tried making a multivalued location ([solr spatial search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch)) field containing locations of various stores belonging to each store, but the results it is giving are erroneous.

{Edit}

I've tried to make a multivalued location field using solr.LatLonType  class as described in the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#QuickStart) containing values of  locations of all the stores  belonging to a particular product, but when you try to sort on this field using geodist() function, it gives erroneous  results(you can check it by looking at the  value of geodist() function which again you can request in fl parameter. I believe that a field belonging to LatLong class can't be made multivalued as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#LatLonType), but can anybody give me some other way of achieving this.

Comment: What have you got so far?...

Answer (score 1):

All your links are pointing at the documentation for older implementation. With Solr 4, there is [new implementation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4).

Also, if you can upgrade, Solr 4.1 added some [extra GEO support](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/changes/Changes.html#4.1.0.new_features) (SOLR-4230). Geo is very rapidly advancing topic within Lucene and Solr, it makes sense to do some double-checking that you are using the latest features.